# ES6 - Loop over class static methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following ES6 class:

```
class MyClass
{
    static static1() {}
    static get static2() {}
    get nonstatic() {}
}
```

...is there a way to loop through only the static methods/properties (including getters)?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of `ES6 Iterate over class methods`?

Comment: Looking at inspector for static methods, they don't get attached to the prototype, so doing -> `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( MyClass )` would get you the static methods, and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( MyClass.prototype )` would get you the normal methods.

Comment: @Jonasw `MyClass[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`

Comment: @Jonasw  I think methods as default are not enumerable, so this returns nothing.. :(

Comment: `Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Api)).filter(([, {value}]) => typeof value === 'function').map(([prop]) => prop)`